# iOS in app asking password next time the app run

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-app in my iOS game. The in-app works, but every time I test it (with the test account), the next time I run my app, it asks my login/password as soon as I load the app store products (which happen as soon as the app launch). If I cancel, it will asks again for the user credentials next time the app run, and so on until the user enter the login/password.

Is this an issue with the sandbox or a problem with my implementation? How can I fix that?

Here is the relevant parts of my code used to load products/purchase:

```
class InAppIos::Private {
public:

    // ...

    void loadProducts(const std::vector<std::string> & identifiers) {
        NSMutableSet *nsids = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:identifiers.size()];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < identifiers.size(); ++i) {
            [nsids addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:identifiers[i].c_str()]];
        }

        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:nsids];
        request.delegate = productRequestDelegate;

        [request start];
    }

    void onProductsResponse(SKProductsResponse *response) {
        unsigned int count = response.products.count;

        InAppProductList products;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            Pointer<InAppProduct> product(new InAppProductIos((SKProduct *)[response.products objectAtIndex:i]));
            products.push_back(product);

            productMap[product->getIdentifier()] = product;
        }

        listener->onProductsResponse(products);
    }

    // ...
};

void InAppProductIos::buy(unsigned int quantity) {
    if (!InApp::get()->isInAppEnabled()) {
        MessageBox::showMessageBox("Error", "Cannot process payment.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct: product];
    payment.quantity = quantity;

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this happens because you try to restore the transactiona, or you haven't removed it from the payment queue.